# what is the difference between eclipse Touchpoint Instruction Advices?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

At this link there are eclipse touchpoint advices

https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_customizing_metadata.html

At the link there is :

instructions.{phase} = {raw actions}

Where {phase} is a p2 installation phase (collect, configure, install, uninstall, unconfigure, etc)

Here what is the difference between phases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase defines **if and when** an action is executed:

- **On install**: collect → validate → install / initconfig → configure → verify
- **On update**: collect → validate → update / migrate → configure → verify
- **On uninstall**: validate → uninstall / unconfigure → verify

See [Eclipse Wiki - Equinox p2 Engine - Extra Notes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Engine#Extra_Notes)